# Stuck with a code error: expecting IDENTIFIER

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

The code below is Verilog code. I get the following error:

```
vlog -work work -stats=none C:/intelFPGA/18.1/lab1-1.v
Model Technology ModelSim - Intel FPGA Edition vlog 10.5b Compiler 2016.10 Oct  5 2016
-- Compiling module combinational_circuit
** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/intelFPGA/18.1/lab1-1.v(4): near "1": syntax error, unexpected INTEGER NUMBER, expecting IDENTIFIER or TYPE_IDENTIFIER or NETTYPE_IDENTIFIER.
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. Can someone help me understand the error message?

```
module combinational_circuit (A,B,C,D,Z);
    input A,B,C,D;
    output Z;
    wire 1,2,3,4,5;

    and a1 (1,A,C,D);
    or o1 (2,1,B);
    nor n1 (3,D,B);
    nand n2 (4,A,3);
    not n3 (5,4);

    xor x1 (Z,2,5);
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

Wire names must not start with a number.  You could rename all your wires like:

```
wire w1,w2,w3,w4,w5;
```

You need to change every line of your code to match the new wire names:

```
and a1 (w1,A,C,D);
```

etc.

This is true for all kinds of identifiers, not just wire names.
From IEEE-Std 1800-2017, section 5.6 *Identifiers, keywords, and system names*:

> The first character of a simple identifier shall not be a digit or $ ;
> it can be a letter or an underscore.